# Android Studio Firebase Storage getting Url error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have looked into every single possible solution but I still don't seem to get what I am doing wrong or what the "user" should be.

Here is my code:

```
mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
mStorage.child("kana@kana.ee.jpeg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            Picasso.with(MyProfile.this).load(uri).into(viewImage);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            Toast.makeText(MyProfile.this, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

This is the file in firebase storage.
[image]

From all the articles I have read it says that something like this is necessary:

```
storageRef.child("users/me/profile.png").getDownloadUrl().getResult();
```

I tried it with "users" and "me" and both of them alone but nothing seems to work. What should I do or what should I replace "users" with.

Answer (score 0):

```
storageRef.child("users/me/profile.png").getDownloadUrl().getResult();
```

This code means get inside users folder then me folder then get the download url for profile.png.
But if your file is in not inside any directory then you can just use this

```
storageRef.child("profile.png").getDownloadUrl().getResult();
```

But in your case your file is `"profile.jpeg"` but you are trying to download `"profile.jpeg"`
That is why it is not finding any child.

Comment: Thats what I also thought but it is still not finding the file

Comment: wait your file is jpeg and you are trying to download a png

Comment: I did try png, jpeg, jpg and all of those files yet none of them worked